# Batch update operation in a restful web API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

Thats my URI to trigger the action: api/lessonplanner/WhatShouldIWriteHere

Even when I would append the list of id`s to the URI like /lessonplanner/?id=1&id=2&id=3

That would get me nowhere because the relation from the property_to_update to the id will be lost.

I do not want to make 10 update requests over the wire.

How can batch updates with a restful URI ever be possible if the URI must be unique thats not possible.

So what can I do to have restful urls even for bulk update or should I not think about that having just a single page app as consumer not a developer?

```
[Route("")]
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody] LessonplannerSaveRequest request)
{
    _service.SaveLessonplanner(request);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: I am not a REST expert so this is just a suggestion and may not be the best (RESTful) solution. But in this case I would design my URI the same way you did but instead of passing values in the query string, I would pass them as a JSON object. And would always treat it as a batch update.

Comment: Exactly this way I do it see the FromBody attribute I used.

Comment: I have no idea yet wether this link: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web+API+Request+Batching makes it more RESTful but it seems to solve something. I say "something" because I am still unsure whats the advantage of this feature to my approach. maybe someone needs it so I post it here :)